# Could I use Patdown+ to steal a Revitaliser Gem from a Battle Researcher's Coromon that's holding one?

Tags: coromon

I saw a Revitaliser Gem on an enemy Coromon before I got my Patdown+ somewhere in Thunderous Cave, but the Wiki doesn't say that such a trainer exists, so I can't confirm the heart-shaped icon I saw...

But if I had Patdown+ at the time, could I have stolen the gem for myself, getting it earlier than intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. It seems like Revitaliser Gems are one of the things a random encounter Coromon can be carrying by the time of the Donar Island area, and might even be possible before then.

I was likely correct that I mistook a random encounter for a Researcher encounter.

I found four Revitaliser Gems on two Tinshels and a Fiddly on the Donar Island water's edge, and a Serpike in the Scorching Sands, and stole them for myself.